# How do you set write concern to 0 on Ruby MongoDB bulk_write?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

[The Ruby driver tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/#bulk-operations) states:

> The second argument to the method is options defining whether the operations should be executed in order and what write concern should be used.

But it doesn't say *how* to set the write concern. I've tried every way I can possibly think of:

```
collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered: false, w: 0)
collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered: false, write: 0)
collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered: false, writeConcern: 0)
collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered: false, write: {w: 0})
```

None of them work, and the function still raises a `BulkWriteError` complaining about duplicate key errors.

So how do you set write concern to 0 when using `bulk_write`?

---

<sub>I'm using MongoDB Ruby driver version 2.0</sub>

Comment: "Write concern" has nothing to do with "duplicate keys". In "legacy" operations a `{ "w": 0 }` is "truly" "fire and forget". WIth Bulk operations this is not the case. You should be using "upserts" rather than ignoring errors from "duplicate" inserts. Better yet use the `.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` variant in your driver rather than the basic command "bulk_write". Then just deal with errors reported in the response, which are not an exception in that case.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Very informative, thanks. You can probably rephrase your comment into an answer that I can accept. Did I actually set write concern to 0 in any of my attempts? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave it to [Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208883/how-do-you-set-write-concern-to-0-on-ruby-mongodb-bulk-write/31215316#comment50419651_31208883) to get credit for a proper answer, but I would just like to share my solution. I use bulk writes like this in several locations, so I wrote a function for specifically ignoring duplicate errors:

```
def ignore_bulk_write_duplicates
  fail "Expected a block" unless block_given?

  begin
    yield
  rescue Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError => e
    e.result[:write_errors].each { |error|
      if error["code"] == 11000
        # Duplicate error is OK
      else
        raise
      end
    }
  end
end
```

And I use it like this:

```
ignore_bulk_write_duplicates {
    collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered: false, w: 0)
}
```

At this point I'm assuming that `w: 0` sets write concern to 0, but I have yet to confirm that... Eagerly awaiting Blake's upcoming answer :-)